# c# webservice response

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a small web service that returns an xml. at the top of the xml it says: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> . Is there a way I can change the webservice so it wont include this line in the response?

TY

Answer (score 0):

It is usually good practice to keep this header. Is there a particular reason you don't want it?

Comment: I have a vbscript that calls this webservice and getting an error. I think it can't find  the Nodes because of this header. 

please look at my other question, describing the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693970/vbscript-xml-problem

Comment: I have posted an answer on your other question. You should perhaps consider closing this one?

Answer (score 0):

Not if you keep using the webservices classes.

Moreover imho it would make absolutely no sense to remove the xml header.